# GLSL: Changing more than two  vertex dimensions crashes shader

Tags: ios, memory, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, shader

For testing purposes I am trying to set the position of every vertex to zero. But If I try to change more than two dimensions (and it doesn't matter which), the shader crashes silently. Can anybody clue me into what is going on here? My code:

```
static const float  vertices[12] = {
                -0.5,-0.5, 0.0,
                0.5,-0.5, 0.0,
                -0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
                0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
            };
glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)vertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);            
glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&modelViewProjection.data[0]);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 4);
```

And my shader:

```
attribute vec4 vertexPosition;
uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;

void main()
{
    vec4 temp = vertexPosition;
    temp.x = 0.0;
    temp.y = 0.0;
    temp.z = 0.0; // Can set any 2 dimensions (e.g. x and y or y and z)
                  // to zero, but not all three or the shader crashes.

    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(temp.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: What means "shader crashes"? Shaders cannot crash; maybe you mean that it has undefined behavior?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean by that is that the iOS app (running on an iPhone 4S) freezes (with no stack trace or anything), but I am assuming that it is the shader that is responsible.

Comment: Could you post all of your C code? There is something more going on there than what's in the shader.

Comment: You can also try doing

`gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(0,0,0,1)`

if you just want to set to zero for now.  that will help narrow your problem down to this, or other code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you declare `vertexPosition` as a `vec4`, but you are only passing 3 `float`s per vertex in your C code? I think the part about your `temp` vector is a red herring.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tested this by changing the shader to use Vec3 inputs, but it is still crashing. :(